# (Flutter/Dart) - How to convert double? to double

Tags: flutter, dart

anyways to convert double? to double

because i got this message with no auto fix
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is from null-safety, the type double? means that it could be either a double, or null, but your parameter only accepts a double, and no null.

For this, you can "force" the use of 'non-null' variable by adding a ! at the end of your variable, but be careful when doing this.

```
CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
    zoom: 15,
)
```

You can learn more about null-safety syntax and principles on the official documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

```
Type? // nullable
Type  // non-null
```

The `?` at the end of any type (in this case `double`) indicates that the value could be null. While `double` only ensures it is non-null.

Read [dart null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

define :
double latitude = 0.0;